# How to stop view resizing after unhiding the NavigationBar

Tags: ios4, uinavigationcontroller, view, resize

I have a view with a `UITabBar` and the navigation bar is initially hidden.  When I press the next tab I want the nav bar to be shown, but when I do this using `setNavigationBarHidden:` the view gets resized, and the tabbar is pushed out of the screen.  How do I setup the views to where they won't get resized?  Or get resized properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to check your [`autoresizingMask`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask)s. You can adjust them programmatically or via IB. `Autosizing` is available in the `Size Inspector` on the right.

You will mostly have to change the tab bar's mask to fix it to bottom and left. Rest of the subviews will have to be handled as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

or
after that

set urview frame to exactly for 44reduce(which is navingation bar height) from height.